# Merging two table using SQL to change column data in single row

Tags: mysql, sql

Looking to merge two tables in a way that data from table2 add as row against data in table1.
Kind of confused. New to sql so looking for some suggestions here.

Table1

```
campID  adID    decID   
camp1   ad1    dec1 
camp1   ad1    dec2 
camp1   ad1    dec3
```

Table2

```
decID   decType
dec1    1
dec2    2
dec3    3
```

output i am expecting

```
campID  adID    decIDTypeA  decIDTypeB  decIDTypeC
camp1   ad1      dec1         dec2        dec3
```

Can someone please help me in writing query.
I tried

```
select 
t1.campID,
t1.adID,
case(
when t1.decID = t2.decID and t2.decType = 7 then t2.decID
END as decIDTypeA
when t1.decID = t2.decID and t2.decType = 7 then t2.decID
END as decIDTypeB
when t1.decID = t2.decID and t2.decType = 7 then t2.decID
END as decIDTypeC
from table1 as t1
JOIN
on table2 as t2
```

but its wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may join the two tables and then apply pivoting logic:

```
SELECT
    t1.campID,
    t1.adID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t2.decType = 1 THEN t1.decID END) AS decIDTypeA,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t2.decType = 2 THEN t1.decID END) AS decIDTypeB,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t2.decType = 3 THEN t1.decID END) AS decIDTypeC
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.decID = t2.decID
GROUP BY
    t1.campID,
    t1.adID;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo